# Comparing a list against a tuple

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to compare a `list` of values against a list of `tuples`. For example:

```
list = [1.0, 2.0]

list_of_tuples = [(3, 1.0, 'a'), (4, 2.0, 'b'), (5, 3.0, 'c')]
```

Ideally what I am trying to do is take the list of tuples and check to see if all the values in that list are present in the other one. In the case of the example lists I provided above 1.0 and 2.0 are present but 3.0 is not. Another problem with this is that the location of the values in the list of tuples is going to be unknown when the comprehension takes place (which isn't the case in the example I provided above) so I'm not actually sure if it is possible to do what I am trying to do.

Any help with this would be appreciated, or an alternative solution would be helpful as well.

Comment: There must be some criteria for the location of the value being compared. Or is it ok if you compare all the values in individual tuples? If that's the case just flatten the list as @Kounis suggested.

Comment: how about *flattening* the `list` of `tuple`s and making your life enjoyable again?

Comment: @hspandher Comparing all the values in the tuples is fine. Not worried about performance at the moment, just looking for a workable solution!

Comment: On a second read your question does not make it clear what it is that you are trying to do...

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Esentially I want to make sure that all the values in the list are present in the list of tuples but there aren't any extra values. In the case I provided above 3.0 is present in the tuples but not in the list, so that would be a failing case.

Comment: @BeeNag I *think* you're after something like `set(list).issuperset(val for tup in list_of_tuples for val in tup)`...

Comment: but at which position? any? Also simply by the lenght of the two lists you can deduct (at least for the example provided) that there will be extra values in the list of tuples..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes it could be at any position

Comment: @JonClements I do not *think* so..

Comment: @JonClements can you explain that? Not sure what that is doing.

Comment: @BeeNag Check my answer, if it works for you.

Comment: @hspandher just checking it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just one value of the tuple must be in the `list`, then this should give you the list of tuples which are invalid.

```
filter(lambda values: not any(value in list for value in values), list_of_tuples)
```

Otherwise, if all values must be in the list

```
filter(lambda values: not all(value in list for value in values), list_of_tuples)
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `filter` here?

Comment: Seems succinct to me. Why? Would you prefer list comprehension?

Comment: I have to agree, but here's the thing... I don't really like list comprehension. I always found functional approach to be more readable. Unfortunately, Guido tends to disagree however.

Comment: @hspandher what is the best way to inspect the object returned by the first function? At the moment it just returns something like <filter object at 0x1035c7a58>

Comment: Ok, so you are using python3 in which filter returns a generator. To get it to work loop over it, or call `list()` on it. Or use list comprehensions instead as @JonClements  suggested.

Comment: Yep cheers that is working for me know! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
flt=[]
for tup in list_of_tuples: 
    flt.extend(tup)
for val in lst:
    if val in flt:
        print val
    else:
        print 'failed'
```

Also, never call a var by a built-in name. call it `lst`, not `list`

Comment: Just to note - you don't need to convert `tup` to a list - `list.extend` takes any iterable.

Comment: Or just write it as `flt = [val for tup in list_of_tuples for val in tup]`... (and you might as well make it a `set` instead of a list... for O(1) instead of O(N) lookups

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive search algorithm that will return a list of indices at which you can recover the found value (the address reads right to left.  There's probably a way to append them in the other direction):

```
def recursive_search(searchable, value):
    address = []
    if _recursive_search(searchable, value, address):
        return address
    else:
        raise Exception("Value not found!")

def _recursive_search(searchable, value, address):
    if hasattr(searchable, '__iter__'): # check if searchable is a list or a tuple
        for i in range(len(searchable)):
            if _recursive_search(searchable[i], value, address):
                address.append(i)
                return True
        else:
                return False
    else:
        if searchable == value:
            return True

#recursive_search([[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]], 11) -> [0,2,1]
```

**EDIT** If you want to apply that over a list of values, you can use `map` or some such.  `map(lambda x: recursive_search(list_of_tuples, x), list)`

**EDIT** If you want to search the OTHER direction as well (which it seems you do in your question), you can combine a recursive map function with `recursive_search`...

```
def recursive_map(some_func, thing_to_map_over):
    some_func = some_func or recursive_map
    if hasattr(thing_to_map_over, '__iter__'):
        return map(lambda x: recursive_map(some_func, x), thing_to_map_over)
    else:
        return some_func(thing_to_map_over)
```

So `recursive_map(lambda x: recursive_search(list, x), list_of_tuples)` will tell you if everything in `list_of_tuples` is in list, and where those things are located.